# Is there a way to merge circles and their areas in D3 JS?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, bubble-chart

EDIT: I originally asked about the *sum* of areas. I'm actually looking for the **average**.

I've been creating a bubble chart to show some data in D3, and I'm just wondering if anyone knows  if it's possible to merge two bubbles to create a bigger bubble.

That is, two bubbles whose area shows percentage data joining together to create a larger circle, whose area is equal to the average percentage of the smaller two.

I ask this here because I want to know if anyone thinks this is possible before trying it out myself! As if not, it may be worth just sticking to the regular bubble chart.

For example, I currently have the bubbles starting out in this position:
[Starting position of the bubble chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEpYa.png)

And then after I press the button to sort them by gender, this happens:
[Position of bubbles after sorting by gender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7A7D.png)

My issue is that the size of the bubbles relates to a percentage, and so having them bunch up like that makes it look like a sum. I was wondering if I could have them merge to form one large bubble each, showing the average of each group...

Comment: Can you post a sketch or link to example / picture ?

Comment: Can you not just do literally that? A circle with the combined area of two smaller circles with radii r1 and r2 will have a radius of sqrt(r1² + r2²)

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question with pictures and edited to clarify what I'm asking for. Sorry for any confusion.